# How to set texture dynamically on MeshPhongMaterial?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to set the texture on THREE.MeshPhongMaterial but the texture does not load. 
My code:

```
let earth_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(450, 10, 10)
let earth_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  emissive: 0xffffff
})
let earth = new THREE.Mesh(earth_geometry, earth_material)
loadImage(earth_material, '/img/earth.jpg')
scene.add(earth)

function loadImage(material, url) {
  let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(url, (e) => {
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    texture.anisotropy = 8
    material.map = texture
    material.needsUpdate = true
  })
```

If I change the material to `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()` the texture is loaded. 
Why does it not work with `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial`?

Answer (score 2):

Might have something to do with your texture variable?
I think you are setting he texture variable, after you are trying to use it.
the `e` argument in the loader callback is actually the loaded texture.
Try this..

```
function loadImage(material, url) {
  let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
  loader.load(url, (texture) => {
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
    texture.anisotropy = 8
    material.map = texture
    material.needsUpdate = true
    // maybe need this too..
    material.map.needsUpdate = true;
  })
```